# MASM - Concatenating strings

Tags: string, assembly, string-concatenation, masm, masm32

For reference, here is the question I'm working from.

> Write a procedure named `Str_concat` that concatenates a source string to the end of a target string. Sufficient space must be available in the target string before this procedure is called.

I'm not looking for code (though I'll take it if it makes it easier to explain). I want to know why it places the caveat that there must be sufficient space in the target string.

I haven't written anything yet because this is my first time really reading the question and I like to plot before I type. I understand that I will need to increment the target string by Lenghtof to point to, and overwrite, the null-terminator. Then loop by length of the source to pull everything over. So why worry about the space in the target; aren't strings just contiguous arrays of characters and, as such, can be extended indeterminately?

Or have I missed some important note in my reference book?

Comment: How do you know what's being stored beyond the end of the allocated buffer? In the best case you'll get a segmentation fault, in the worst case you'll overwrite some other data and the program will continue running in a corrupted state.

Comment: Strings take up space in memory. That memory needs to be allocated for the string and not any thing else. If you extend a string beyond the space allocated for it, then the string can overwrite something else or something else can overwrite the string.

Comment: @Lee in that the case, say the string was initialized normally ( enclosed in parentheses and null-terminated), wouldn't the allocated buffer be only up until the trailing 0? How would I concatenate then while staying within "scope"?

Comment: In assembly language, enclosing a string in parentheses and NUL terminating it doesn't allocate any storage for the string. You need to use a storage allocating directive like DB for the string exist anywhere in memory when the program is run. You can use these directives to provide additional space for the string, or to create a bigger buffer to copy the string into. You probably need to go back in your book and learn about how to use these storage allocating directives.

Comment: @Ross Ridge Oh, ok. Thank you. I believed that the storage directive was allocating space for each element in the array, so a normal string just used BYTE. I had thought using any larger directive would be wasting space.

Comment: You want store each element of string in a byte, since that's what a string is (at least in your case), but you can use the BYTE directive (also known as DB) to allocate more bytes beyond the end of the string. Eg. `BYTE 'Hello', 0, 100 DUP (?)`